# kafka crashing when consuming messages

Tags: apache-kafka

kafka used to work perfectly on my own computer. i'm working on another computer now where it says

> ERROR Error while creating log for __consumer_offsets-41 in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel) java.io.IOException: Map failed at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:940) at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.(AbstractIndex.scala:126) at kafka.log.TimeIndex.(TimeIndex.scala:54) at kafka.log.LogSegment$.open(LogSegment.scala:635) at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:573) at kafka.log.Log.(Log.scala:290) at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:2141) at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1(LogManager.scala:701) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) at kafka.log.LogManager.getOrCreateLog(LogManager.scala:659) at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1(Partition.scala:199) at kafka.utils.Pool$$anon$2.apply(Pool.scala:61) at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) at kafka.utils.Pool.getAndMaybePut(Pool.scala:60) at kafka.cluster.Partition.getOrCreateReplica(Partition.scala:195) at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$makeLeader$3(Partition.scala:373) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233) at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937) at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425) at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70) at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69) at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226) at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104) at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$makeLeader$1(Partition.scala:373) at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251) at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:259) at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:367) at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$makeLeaders$5(ReplicaManager.scala:1170) at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:145) at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:235) at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:228) at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40) at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:145) at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:1168) at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:1080) at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:185) at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:110) at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:69) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method) at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:937) ... 41 more [2019-03-25 14:55:00,296] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Stopping serving replicas in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager) [2019-03-25 14:55:00,296] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=0] Error while making broker the leader for partition Topic: __consumer_offsets; Partition: 41; Leader: None; AllReplicas: ; InSyncReplicas: in dir None (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)

this error appears whenever i try to consume a topic by issuing the following command:

> bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic UpdateObserver --from-beginning

my java version is :

java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)

ps: deleting the tmp directory doesnt solve the problem, it just makes me able to launch kafka again, once i want to consume from a given topic it crashes

Comment: Kafka does not currently officially support Windows so your mileage may vary: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#os

Comment: for dev. purposes, you could run Kafka in docker under windows

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue. Upgrade the Java version to 16.0.1 will solve my problem.
Also set JAVA_HOME to 16 version without bin folder. for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1